# config_test.yml settings not appearing in debug:config

Tags: symfony

When I run

```
app/console --env=test debug:config security
```

I still see my production settings from `security.yml`, not my test settings from `config_test.yml`. Any idea why?

Comment: Please paste your `config_test.yml` content.

Comment: I'm obviously not going to post my *actual* security configuration here, but you can see a fake example in my self-answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I had to recursively override *every single item* in my security config. For example, imagine my `security.yml` looks like this:

```
firewalls:
    firewall_a:
        pattern: ^/api
        complicated_oauth_security: {}
    firewall_b:
        pattern: ^/
        complicated_username_password_security: {}
```

And imagine for testing I want something that looks like this:

```
firewalls:
    only_one_firewall_for_everything:
        pattern: ^/
        http_basic: ~
```

The actual content of `config_test.yml` needs to look like this:

```
firewalls:
    firewall_a:
        # I can leave out "pattern", since that isn't changing.
        complicated_oauth_security: false
        http_basic: ~
    firewall_b:
        complicated_username_password_security: false
        http_basic: ~
```

I thought that re-declaring a firewall in `config_test.yml` would replace the entire thing, but that's not how it works. You must override each individual item that you want to change.